# Бессоюзное cложное предложение

Tags: пунктуация

**Его связала с князем еще одна долгая нить () нить взаимной нужды и приязни, у которой есть начало и есть конец.**

Вопрос: Какой знак ставится на месте пропуска ()? Я думаю, что двоеточие, но в источнике указана запятая. Можете указать на мою ошибку? Почему не двоеточие, а запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным определительным, причем главное предложение осложнено обособленным приложением пояснительного характера.

Его связала с князем **еще одна** долгая нить, (**а именно какая**) нить взаимной нужды и приязни, у которой есть начало и есть конец.

Обособленный член имеет значение пояснения.

**Двоеточие**, которое тоже выражает **пояснительное** значение,  обычно ставится в предложениях с обобщающим словом или в бессоюзном сложном предложении.

**Примечание.** В конце предложения пояснительные конструкции при отсутствии союза  могут обособляться **тире,** но в данном случае используются запятые,  так как заканчивается предложение **придаточным определительным**, которое может относиться  и **к первой части предложения**.

[Розенталь. § 23. Пояснительные конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119)